# JWT using Firebase to maintain login without cookies

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm creating a website which necessitate a login for some contents. I have succeeded to use JWT library but i don't find and don't understand how to maintain login without the use of cookies (my temp solution).

Can you explain me what is the best solution to give JWT between pages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can store the JWT in the localstorage of the user's browser. And with every request, you should pass that token into the Authorization header.

On the backend, you need to verify the token and extract informations about the connected user to return data based on his profile.

Comment: Ok thank you so much i'm going to learn on Authorization header :)

Comment: I read this topic : https://gist.github.com/soulmachine/b368ce7292ddd7f91c15accccc02b8df#:~:text=For%20Web%20Apps%3A%20If%20you,token%20at%20the%20sixth%20day. So the best way to dealt JWT is to store token in localStorage or HTTP only cookie and using refresh token ?

Comment: Indeed, this is the best approach. Just make sure that you don't include any plaintext password or critical data in the body of the token, because it's a base64 string and can be decoded. Check out this website for that: https://jwt.io/

Comment: Yes thank you so mush, the most critical data that I stored in my JWt is the userId :)